# SSRS Nested Table - Shrink Outer Row if No Data?

Tags: nested, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, shrink

I have an SSRS report with a table, which is set to a stored procedure.  There are too many columns to fit on 1 row wide.  I made 3 tables and split the fields into those 3 tables.  In the first table, after the header row and the field row, I added another row, inside the group, and merged all columns.  I dragged the 2nd table and dropped it into that 3rd row of the first table.  The 2nd table only has 1 field (a notes field), which is commonly empty.  I have a visibility on that tablix's properties that if the notes field = "" it's hidden.

All of that works correctly.  The problem is, that row of the main table doesn't shrink, so there is a huge space.  How do I fix that? Is there a better way to handle this?  This report has a lot of sections, this is just one.  This one section has 7 fields, which needs to be split onto a couple of rows, but because there may be more than 1 identifying record, I want to keep all the fields with each record.

I hope that all makes sense.  I'm working on VS 2012, with data on a 2014 SQL server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I bet if you first placed a Rectangle to wrap your table you will find that the rectangle will shrink the parent table down.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  This is close to what I ended up with.  My colleague took a look, and shrunk the height of the outer table row, which has the nested table in it.  She made it like 0.  It auto expands, if there is something, and otherwise, is 0.  Works like a charm!  just need a good documentation piece to explain that, so if anyone else has to work on the report, they will understand the purpose for this set up.